# How can i use custom function in class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have this view

```
class UserView(GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        pass

    def post(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        pass
```

This works fine with this url

```
url(r'^user$', UserView.as_view(),name='user'),
```

but i want  to have custom url

```
def  custom():
      pass
```

I want that

```
url(r'^user/custom/$', UserView.as_view(custom),name='user'),
```

How can i do that

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to have a custom url for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
]
```

> Any arguments passed to as_view() will override attributes set on the
>   class. In this example, we set template_name on the TemplateView. A
>   similar overriding pattern can be used for the url attribute on
>   RedirectView.

If you want a 'custom' url, Use the Functions Based views

**Urls**

```
url(r'^user/custom/$', custom, name='user'),
```

**Views**

```
def custom(request):
     # your custom logic
     # return something
```

**Edit 1***
If you want pass parameters to the CBV.

```
class View(DetailView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    model = MyModel
    # custom parameters
    custom = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return queryset.get(custom=self.custom)
```

**Url**

```
url(r'^about/', MyView.as_view(custom='custom_param')),
```

Comment: can i make that parameter optional in url so that if i see that custom in url then i can do differentb stuff in POST othwise /user will  work

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually i need to support the legagy application which does three different works based on url . They are all POST . originally we had three different function views for that but now i have chnaged that to class based views, so i was thinking what will be the best way to do it, one way i was thinking is to pass separate variable in as_view() and then do stuff based on that

Comment: @user3214546 did you find a solution for your problem? Dealing with the same task right now